# Publish on user's wall using application's name

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm using Facebook GRAPH API to publish on user's wall.

It works fine, but I'm encountering a little problem:

My publication appears on the user's wall with the user's name, as if he published himself

I want to publish on his wall but with my application's name

How can I do this ?

Answer (score 0):

First you need user post stream permission. After you get user credential, then you can try send $_POST with structure like these

```
$stream_data = array(
                    'access_token' => $user_access_token,
                    'caption'      => 'From Your App',
                    'description'  => 'Your App description',
                    'link'         => 'http://yourapp.com',
                    'picture'      => 'http://yourapp.com/assets/img/someicon.png',
                    'name'         => $user_sess_name.' just started uses Your App name.',
                );
```

to `https://graph.facebook.com/1234/feed` (1234 is a user id) to create a feed stream.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to post on a user's wall and have it attributed to the app itself, only users may write on each other's walls, there's no way for an app or Page to write on a Profile's wall. 
toopay's answer is a good example of posting to a user's wall from an app, but that post would be attributed to the user whose access token you use

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so you can post on user's wall with the app name, You can use the below code to post on user wall and it will say on the Bottom **VIA app name**

```
$fb = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => '2420527xxxxxxx',
  'secret' => 'a6b14d618xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
));

try {
     $attachment = array(
       'message' => '',
       'access_token' => $fb->getAccessToken(),
       'name' => 'Attachment Name',
       'caption' => 'Attachment Caption',   
       'link' => 'http://www.xxxxxxx.com/app/',
       'description' => 'Description .....',
       'picture' => 'http://www.xxxxxxx.com/logo.xxx',
       'actions' => array(array('name' => 'Action Text','link' =>'http://www.xxx.com/app/'))
      );
$result = $fb->api('/'.$fb->getAppId().'/feed/', 'post', $attachment);  
    echo $result;
    }catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
   echo $e->getMessage()."\n";
}
```

Try it..!!!